# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I tried for 3 days to add one row to my database with entityframework but I couldn't :| .. Now I do all of essentials work for adding row to database... in the end I got this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll - Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

I executed the database for several times but...!

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class BuyForm : Form
    {
        public BuyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void BuyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        notebookEntities database = new notebookEntities();



        private void buyGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BuyForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            buytbl tbl = new buytbl
            {
                name = bnameTextBox.Text,
                price = int.Parse(bpriceTextbox.Text.ToString()),
                date = dateTimePicker1.Value,
                deadline = dateTimePicker2.Value,
                buyername = bbuyerTextBox.Text.ToString(),
                count = int.Parse(bcountTextBox.Text.ToString()),
                profit = int.Parse(bprofitTextBox.Text.ToString())



            };


            database.buytbls.Add(tbl);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = database.buytbls.ToList();
            database.SaveChanges();


        }
    }
}
```

and the table:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6

    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class buytbl
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int price { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
            public int  profit { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime deadline { get; set; }
            public string buyername { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

help me please!... <3

Comment: **"See the inner exception for details."** And the inner exception said....?

Comment: Could you please add inner exception details, because looking at your code, it is hard to tell what is breaking. but you can try few thing, check if it is datetime2 conversion error as you are inserting dates, check if you are passing required values as null.

Comment: it doesn't have any inner!

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is any mismatch in column names or Foreign key mapping name between your model class and your actual DB table. That generally would be the cause of this error.

Answer (score -1):

Update your model. The context should sync with DB